# How to find where Scheme calls integer-less?

Tags: scheme, sicp, mit-scheme

I'm doing [exercise 2.29 from SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%25_thm_2.29), using MIT/GNU Scheme (Release 9.1.1). Currently I'm debugging following solution

```
(define (balanced mobile)
  ; weight-b returns weight of mobile if it is balanced, otherwise - negative value
  (define (weight-b mobile)
    (if (pair? mobile)
      (let ((lb (weight-b (branch-structure (left-branch mobile))))) ; compute left balance
        (if (< lb 0)
          -1 ; left submobile is not balanced, so this mobile too
          (let ((rb (weight-b (branch-structure (right-branch mobile))))) ; compute right balance
            (display "rb ") (display lb) (newline) ; DEBUG log
            (if (< rb 0)
              -1 ; right submobile is not balanced, so this mobile too
              (if (=
                (* lb (branch-length (left-branch mobile)))
                (* rb (branch-length (right-branch mobile)))
              )
                (+ lb rb) ; finally, completely balanced case, return total weight
                -1 ; submobiles are balanced, but torques are different
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
    mobile ; single weight is already balanced by itself
  )
  (> (weight-b mobile) 0)
)
```

It gives me error "The object ((1 5) (1 5)), passed as the first argument to integer-less?, is not the correct type." At first, from name `integer-less?` assumed that it is problem with `(< lb 0)` or `(< rb 0)`, but I logged lb and rb, and they are integer.

My code does not call `integer-less?` explicitly, so I'm not sure where to look then. Could you please tell what is `ingeger-less?`, where to find it in my program, or in general, how to locate line number in Scheme code where error happened.

I tried `integer-less?` in REPL, but it responds with "Unbound variable: integer-less?", and googling was not successful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess `integer-less?` is part of your scheme's implementation and is called when `<` is comparing integers. If so, you would need to go looking at the source code of your scheme.

If that is the case then it might be complaining because it expects both the arguments of `<` to be integers, but at least one isn't.  That may be because `weight-b` does not always return an integer.

I don't think `(if (pair? mobile) ...` has an alternate clause so if `mobile` is not a pair then the result of `weight-b` may be undefined (the exact behaviour depends on the version of scheme you're using).

Comment: Thank you. I just discovered that I could call `(trace weight-b)` and it will log all calls with arguments and return values, and yes, you are right, my if has no else clause, I messed up with parentheses and it went outside of if. 

And problem was not with calling `<`, arguments for which I logged, but with calling `>` in the end. :D

Comment: You're welcome :-)  Could you update your question (or add a comment) to say which Scheme implementation you are using?  I am curious and it might be helpful for anybody else reading your question.